# Obtaining current ModelView matrix

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, translation

In OpenGL, how do I read the current x/y translation in the modelview matrix? I know that you have to load the current matrix into an array and read the floats from there, but I don't know precisely how to do it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In order to retrieve the current modelview matrix you have to call the [glGetFloatv](http://linux.die.net/man/3/glgetfloatv) function with `GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX` parameter.

```
GLfloat matrix[16]; 
glGetFloatv (GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, matrix);
```

From the documentation:

> `GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX`
>
> params returns sixteen values: the
>   modelview matrix on the top of the
>   modelview matrix stack. Initially this
>   matrix is the identity matrix.

Answer (score 5):

Use [glGlet](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/man_pages/hardcopy/GL/html/gl/get.html)

```
GLfloat matrixf[16];
glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, matrixf);

GLdouble matrixd[16];
glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, matrixd);

GLint matrixi[16];
glGetIntegerv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, matrixi);
```

Comment: 'glet'? or 'get'?